# YUM: updating repo's GPG key

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

Haven't found the answer for this in docs: how often Yum refreshes the GPG key of a repo, if it was obtained from the net? For instance, I've got this repo config:

```
[myrepo]
name=myrepo 
baseurl=http://example.com/repo
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://example.com/gpg.key
```

And the GPG key has been changed on the server, what will trigger YUM to update already imported key?

Comment: AFAIK, deletion of the locally downloaded key.

Comment: @jordanm, looks like that's not the only event. I've discovered that if the package comes from the repo, signed with an unknown key, YUM tries to re-obtain the key using the link provided. If the new key could be downloaded with the old link, it will be added to rpmdb. Although, the old key is still remains in the database and could verify the packages.